# Use existing page as app page in Facebook (2017)

Tags: facebook

I have both a Facebook page and a Facebook app and want to use my existing page as the page for the app. All answers I've found says that the page needs to be changed to "App Page" which is found under "Brands & Products". The problem is that those options aren't available anymore.

Can someone say how to use an existing page as an app page, or confirm that this is no longer possible?

Comment: AFAIK this category is still available when you create a new page, but somehow not any more when changing the category of an already existing page. No idea if that was an intentional change by Facebook though.

Comment: I found the answer myself and posted the solution. Check it out!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I just found out the answer myself, so I'll answer it.

1. First go to your PAGE and choose Edit Page Info in the three dot menu.
2. Under Category, add the tag "App Page". It's important to **REMOVE ANY OTHER TAGS**!
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRxDB.png
3. Then go to your APP at Facebook for Developers and go to Settings - Advanced. Under App Page you'll see a list of all available pages you can choose.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMrBW.png

Comment: The step of removing the other tags is important, thanks :)

Comment: 2021-03-02 There is no "App Page" anymore.